# How to call a static trait method like std::num::Float::epsilon()?

Tags: generics, methods, static, rust

I'm just starting learning Rust a little and I have hit this issue I am unable to solve.

In Rust, there are static methods in std::num::Float trait (and in other traits as well), that take no parameters. That would be ok, but I'm finding them unable to call. I have tried these options:

```
Float::epsilon()         // complains that "type annotations required"
Float::<f32>::epsilon()  // complains "too many type parameters provided"
Float::epsilon::<f32>()  // same thing as the previous one
f32::epsilon()           // I'd love this syntax to work, but it doesn't
```

Has anyone out there tackled this problem? Is it just me being stupid, or is this a real problem within Rust itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static methods on traits are called like `Float::epsilon`. That means that this will work, if you give it a type hint to match against the `Self` type of the trait.

```
use std::num::Float;

let eps: f32 = Float::epsilon();
```

There is a general syntax for calling a particular trait method, if it is impossible to deduce the concrete trait implementor any other way, for example if there is no `Self` in the signature at all:

```
<f32 as Float>::epsilon()
```

or if you have a type parameter `F: Float`:

```
<F as Float>::epsilon()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The general syntax however must have been added recently, because it doesn't work on my local compiler (which is not the bleeding-edge version), but it works on the Rust's website, so I will have to update my compiler. :)

Comment: I found it very interesting that it is possible to call methods on traits directly !